# loop with one new line not multiple JAVA

Tags: java, args, system.out

Java Newbie Here,
So i am attempting to write a program that can set the number of hello worlds, and the number of exclamation points that follow it, entering these value using the command line arguments. i have in a manner done it but the output format is wrong.
Desired result 
"Hello World !!!!
"Hello World !!!!"
Attempt 1
"Hello World !
!
!
!" (this continues down)
what I am Getting, attempt 2
"Hello World !!!!Hello World!!!!Hello World!!!!"

my code for Attempt 1

```
public class NHelloWorldWE {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int e = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    for (int a = 1; a <= n; a = a + 1) {
        System.out.print("Hello World");
    for (int b = 1; b <= e; b = b + 1) {
        System.out.print("!");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }    
    }

}
}
```

My Code for Attempt 2

```
public class NHelloWorldWE {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int e = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    for (int a = 1; a <= n; a = a + 1) {
        System.out.print("Hello World");
    for (int b = 1; b <= e; b = b + 1) {
        System.out.print("!");
    }    
    }

}

}
```

Comment: if you take a close look at the desired output and the output of your first attempt: what is the difference that makes it wrong?

Comment: sorry I didn'n realise i needed to input breakline  using (< br / >)

Comment: The new line special character is \n, but using .println() works too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a new line print:

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int e = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    for (int a = 1; a <= n; a = a + 1) {
        System.out.print("Hello World");
        for (int b = 1; b <= e; b = b + 1) {
            System.out.print("!");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This one will give you a similar result, but with 1 less exclamation mark in each iteration (I believe this is what you are trying to do)

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int e = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        for (int a = 1; a <= n; a++) {
            System.out.print("Hello World");
            for (int b = 1; b <= e; b++) {
                System.out.print("!");
            }
        e--;
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: awesome the 1st one did the trick, one the second one what is the "e--;" for?

Comment: It will decrease the  e counter so you will print one less exclamation mark each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of your solution:

```
public class NHelloWorldWE {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int e = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
      System.out.print("Hello World");
      for (int b = 0; b < e; b++) {
        System.out.print("!");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

And here is one using streams:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class NHelloWorldWE {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int e = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    final String hello = "Hello World" + Stream.generate(() -> "!")
        .limit(e)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
    Stream.generate(() -> hello)
        .limit(n)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Comment: the first one worked exactly, for what i was after the 2nd doesn't seem to compile for me, regardless could you quickly explain streams and why they would be a useful alternative please?

Comment: The streaming solution requires java 8 or higher to compile. Streams provide an alternative to collections when manipulating data. They're not actually a good fit here, but they are pretty fun to work with. Here is an article from oracle about them: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html